# Query string with anomalous behavior

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to understand the query_string clause in elasticsearch. Specifically, I need to understand the next behavior. After I putted the next document.

```
PUT test/doc/1
{
  "name": "1RD.ISABELA.GRADOS"
}
```

I expect that the next two queries result have one document. But only the last query return 1 document. My question is why the first query is not returning anything?. Could you help me, please?

```
GET test/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "1RD.ISABELA",
            "default_field": "*"
          }
        }
      ]
     }
    }
 }


GET test/_search 
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "1RD.ISABELA.GRADOS",
                "default_field": "*"
              }
            }
          ]
         }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Could you share your index mapping?

Answer (score 0):

If you will run below query

```
GET index28/_analyze
{
  "text": "1RD.ISABELA.GRADOS",
  "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

Response:

```
"tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "1rd.isabela.grados",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 18,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
```

There is a single token generated for entire text. By default, a tokenizer named standard is used. It splits text by whitespace and also removes most symbols, such as commas, periods, semicolons, etc.

So only 1rd.isabela.grados will match this token.

If you will execute below query

```
GET index28/_analyze
{
  "text": "RD ISABELA GRADOS.",
  "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

Response

```
"tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "rd",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 2,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "isabela",
      "start_offset" : 3,
      "end_offset" : 10,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "grados",
      "start_offset" : 11,
      "end_offset" : 17,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    }
  ]
```

3 tokens are generated. SO search on any of these tokens will return the documents